# new, deploy, jssdk return 404

Tags: parse-platform

I got error when I tried to create CouldCode by using

`$parse new CloudCode`

`parse: error with status=404 and body="<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\n<head>\n    <title>404 | Parse</title>\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no\">\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n        html{\n            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;\n            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;   \n        }\n        html,\n        body,\n        .four_oh_four {\n            padding: 0px;\n            margin: 0px;\n            height: 100%;\n            width: 100%;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four {\n            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-38deg, #1AB5C2 0%, #0572E0 100%);\n            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-38deg, #1AB5C2 0%, #0572E0 100%);\n            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-38deg, #1AB5C2 0%, #0572E0 100%);\n            background-image: linear-gradient(128deg, #1AB5C2 0%, #0572E0 100%);\n            font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n            color: #fff;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four .logo {\n            display: block;\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            top: 50px;\n            position: relative;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four .nav {\n            list-style: none;\n            font-weight: 200;\n            font-size: 18px;\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            position: absolute;\n            padding: 0;\n            bottom: 50px;\n            width: 100%;\n            text-align: center;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four .nav li {\n            display: inline-block;\n            margin: 0px 10px;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four .nav a {\n            color: #fff;\n            text-decoration: none;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four .nav a:hover {\n            text-decoration: underline;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four .error {\n            display: block;\n            position: absolute;\n            top: 50%;\n            -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);            \n            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);\n            transform: translateY(-50%);\n            margin: 0;\n            padding: 0;\n            text-align: center;\n            width: 100%;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four h1 {\n            font-weight: 100;\n            font-size: 240px;\n            margin: 0;\n            padding: 0;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four h2 {\n            font-weight: 200;\n            font-size: 28px;\n            margin: 0;\n            padding: 0;\n        }\n        .four_oh_four #emoji {\n            position: relative;\n            top: 40px;\n            background-image: url('/images/404/sprite.png');\n            display: inline-block;\n            width: 200px;\n            height: 230px;\n            background-size: 6000px;\n            background-repeat: no-repeat;\n        }\n        @media (max-width: 500px) {\n            .four_oh_four .logo {\n                top: 30px;\n            }\n            .four_oh_four h1 {\n                font-size: 120px;\n            }\n            .four_oh_four h2 {\n                font-size: 22px;\n            }\n            .four_oh_four #emoji {\n                width: 100px;\n                height: 115px;\n                top: 16px;\n                background-size: 3000px;\n            }\n            .four_oh_four .nav {\n                bottom: 30px;\n            }\n            .four_oh_four .nav li {\n                margin: 5px 14px;\n            }\n        }\n    </style>\n    <script>\n        var emojiCount = 30;\n        function getRandomInt(min, max) {\n            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;\n        }\n\n\n        function catchFeelings() {\n            var emoji = getRandomInt(0, emojiCount - 1)\n            if(window.innerWidth > 400){\n                var bgOffset = (emoji * 200 * -1) + \"px 0px\"\n            } else {\n                var bgOffset = (emoji * 100 * -1) + \"px 0px\"    \n            }\n            document.getElementById('emoji').style.backgroundPosition = bgOffset;\n        }\n    </script>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n\n    <div class=\"four_oh_four\">\n        <img class=\"logo\" src=\"/images/parse-logo.png\" width=\"98\" height=\"31\" />\n\n        <figure class=\"error\">\n            <h1>4<div id=\"emoji\"></div>4</h1>\n            <h2>Oh no, we can’t find that page!</h2>\n        </figure>\n\n        <ul class=\"nav\">\n            <li><a href=\"/\">Home</a>\n            </li>\n            <li><a href=\"/products\">Products</a>\n            </li>\n            <li><a href=\"/pricing\">Pricing</a>\n            </li>\n            <li><a href=\"/docs\">Docs</a>\n            </li>\n            <li><a href=\"/help\">Help</a>\n            </li>\n            <li><a href=\"http://blog.parse.com\">Blog</a>\n            </li>\n        </ul>\n    </div>\n\n</body>\n<script>\n    catchFeelings();\n\n    setTimeout(function () {\n        setInterval(function () {\n            catchFeelings()\n        }, 3000)\n    }, 3000)\n    \n    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {\n        e = e || window.event;\n        switch (e.which || e.keyCode) {\n        case 32:\n            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {\n                setTimeout(function () {\n                    catchFeelings();\n                }, 50 * i)\n            }\n            break;\n\n        default:\n            return;\n        }\n        e.preventDefault();\n    });\n</script>\n\n</html>\n"`

What's the wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Yup, still facing same issue. Let you know, if I figure out something.

Comment: I am seeing this issue as well.

`% parse deploy                                         repos/parse-model NV-MBP
JS SDK version not set, setting it to latest available JS SDK version
parse: error with status=404 and body="<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\n<head>\n    <title>404 | Parse</title>\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues has been resolved. `% parse deploy` again and it will update your cli. Run once again and it will succeed. 

 `% parse deploy                                         repos/parse-model NV-MBP
Downloading binary from https://parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/cli/parse-osx/latest.
Successfully updated binary at: /usr/local/bin/parse`

`% parse deploy                                         repos/parse-model NV-MBP
JS SDK version not set, setting it to latest available JS SDK version
Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/cloud/main.js
Uploading recent changes to hosting...
The following files will be uploaded:
/public/index.html
Finished uploading files
New release is named v1 (using Parse JavaScript SDK v1.4.2)`

Comment: Thank you for your response.
However still I can't create cloudcode.
When I intend to use "parse new" command, It's gonna be frozen.
'
$parse new CloudCode
Downloading binary from https://parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/cli/parse-osx/latest.
'

Comment: Are you saying it just hangs when trying to download the cli?

Comment: Try to delete the file
 `rm /usr/local/bin/parse`
then
`curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash`